# How to have multiple selected item in drop-down if saved in id laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am selecting the multiple id of classes in creating leadtype via explode,how can i get all the selected id of classes in dropdown in edit function

Classes table

**id** 1 **name** class one
**id** 2 **name** class two
**id** 3 **name** class three

Leadtype table

**id** 1 **class_id** 1,2,3,
**id** 2 **class_id** 1,2
**id** 3 **class_id** 2,1

I am saving only id of classes in leadtype table but when i edit i want

all the value selected instead of id

```html
my route 
Route::get('admin/leadtypes/form', 'LeadTypesController@form');  add
Route::post('admin/leadtypes/post', 'LeadTypesController@update'); store
Route::get('admin/leadtypes/form/{id}', 'LeadTypesController@editForm'); edit


Add function 
public function form()    {
          $classes =  Classes::pluck('name','id');
     return view('leadtypes.form',$data,compact('classes'));

        }

My store/update function

 public function update(Request $request)
    {

     
      $data =  \Input::except(array('_token')) ;

                    $rule=array(
                      'name'   => 'required',

                             );

       $validator = \Validator::make($data,$rule);

      if ($validator->fails())
      {
              return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages());
      }
      $inputs = $request->all();

      if(!empty($inputs['id'])){

          $item = LeadTypes::findOrFail($inputs['id']);

      }else{

          $item = new LeadTypes;

      }
      if(is_array($request->name)){
                  $item->name = implode(',', $request->name);
                }
      $item->status = $inputs['status'];
     
      $item->save();
      flash('success','record_added_successfully', 'success');
    return redirect('admin/leadtypes');

    }

edit function 

    public function editForm($id)
    {

      $item = LeadTypes::findOrFail($id);
      $data['active_class']       = 'Lead type';
      $data['title']              = getPhrase('Lead type');
       
    $classes =  Classes::pluck('name','id');
 $item->name =   explode(',', $item->name);

 

     return view('leadtypes.form',$data,compact('item','classes'));


    }

My view dropdown 

{!! Form::select('name[]',  $classes, !empty($item->name) ? $item->name : explode(',',old('name'))  ,['class' =>'form-control ' ,'required'=>'true','multiple'=>'true']); !!}
```

Comment: Just get the `ids` and `names` and feed it to select.

Comment: i am doing it,You can check my above code, but i am not getting any value selected in dropdown ,can you please help me  sir,plz??

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be pushing the LaravelCollective Form::() method to a place it's not happy with.  It is a bit finicky to start, and there are a few issues with what you have above.

The `$item->name` is actually a string as stored, I think.  If it is set in the DB, it is going to come through to your last line of code as a string:

```
!empty($item->name) ? $item->name : explode(...)
```

You need to explode the DB-stored string in the FIRST part of your operation above as well, to get this to match whatever the `$classes` array is for the second parameter in that same statement.  String <--> array won't work, and thus won't ever allow for a value to be selected from the model.

I'm pretty sure this will solve it.  However, I would also possibly reconsider your architecture on this.  Storing those arrays of IDs in a single field (and a field named singular 'name') is a little confusing, and is also making life difficult for you.  Perhaps consider pulling those LeadTypes into their own belongsToMany relationship with their own sub table.  Then you can just store the two ids and simplify everything.  If that works -- but the above should answer your question.

Comment: Can you please guide me through , i have been trying to solve it for the last 3 days, please help me? I want id of class to be stored and get selected item to be in dropdown while editing..

Comment: When i save & edit like this then it comes on my dropdown  $classes =  Classes::pluck('name','**name**');
 $item->name =   explode(',', $item->name);

Comment: But when i do like this  $classes = Classes::pluck('name','**id**'); $item->name = explode(',', $item->name); it doesnot come

Comment: Can anyone answer my question please?